# How to export a single table from phpmyadmin to a comma delimited text file?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I need to export a table from phpmyadmin to a comma delimited text file. I think there is a code but can't seem to find it. I found one but it doesnt work.

I need to export this table because I need to organize it and sort it and add another column so I can add data to this column.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PHPAdmin, if I recall correctly, there is an Export tab. If you click on that, you can select the table(s) you want to export and which format you would like to export the data in. CSV, .zip, .gzip, etc...

Comment: Yes you are right. However I forgot a small detail. I want to export a table but sorted by ID. Can I do this? Currently, it is a bit random. For instance, you have from 1-19 then 5325, then 22,23, and so on...

Answer (score 4):

Execute this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
 INTO OUTFILE 'directory' ->e.g /tmp/myTable.csv(Linux) or C:\myTable.csv(Windows)
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: Hi, there! I used your SQL statement but there is no .txt created in the directory (C:\myTable.csv), but when i call the same statement it returns me: 1086 - File 'C:myTableTest.csv' already exists What's the problem??? Thanks, Tom

Comment: @Tom: You need to either pick a new name for the output file, rename the original one, or do this in a way that will overwrite the original file.

Comment: @Robert: thanks a lot for so quick response!!
my problem is that the C:myTableTest.csv does not exist!!When i run the statement first time everything it's ok,no erros. When i go to my disk C to find myTableTest.csv file,this file doesn't exist!!But when i recall the statement it returns the error 1086 - File 'C:myTableTest.csv' already exists

Comment: @Tom: You need to look at it more carefully. You might think you're in a different folder than you actually are. Also, put the file in a folder, not in the root of the C: drive.

Answer (score 3):

Select the database and click the 'Export' tab. Select the table to export. Use CSV as the format.

Answer (score 2):

As mention before you have a export tab for do things things. But if you want to export a tricky question or a very special ordering you can do as following:

```
Go to View or write your SQL question
In the bottom of the view-page you will have a Export link. 
If you click on that you will now export the question (and its order) 
in any format you chose
```