# Select Group column A with respect Column B not repeat

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the values from a query result that should not repeat with respect to another column.

[image]

In these screenshot, i want to select `function` column only once for each user id and object_id as concated values . For eg., in this screenshot, `delete_portfolio_module` is repeating many times for the user id 32782, so i need to have it only once with the max(`id`),timebox_id,user_id,function,object_id as follows,

```
id           |timebox_id|user_id|function                             |object_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3155     |4         |32799  |add_latest_activity_to_portfolio     |7410
    3137     |4         |32797  |add_latest_activity_to_portfolio     |7408
    3133     |4         |32796  |add_latest_activity_to_portfolio     |7406
    3115     |2         |32782  |delete_portfolio_module              |7381,7382,...,7388,7389
    .
    .
    .
```

Sio, how to achieve this in mysql? Please help...

Comment: @Barranka i played with some Group and Distinct which does not work. So i dont know how to proceed further...

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the two columns: `user_id` and `function` so you can aggregate the remaining columns.

```
SELECT  MAX(ID) ID,
        MAX(timebox_ID) timebox,
        user_ID,
        `function`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(object_ID) objectList
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY user_ID, `function`
```

Comment: This will return only 1 row with the max(id) of the entire result and the group_concat(object_id)

Comment: @Udhay did you test the query? `GROUP_CONCAT()` allows you to concatenate rows instead of column.

Comment: Yup i tried! it is returning only one row. And also is there any reason that you're using MAX() for `timebox_id` also which is not required???

Comment: can you export the sample record into text format and not as image so I can show you the result of the query?

Comment: [How to export a single table from phpmyadmin to a comma delimited text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802410/how-to-export-a-single-table-from-phpmyadmin-to-a-comma-delimited-text-file)

Comment: after you have exposted the table, post the result along with your question.