# Can't insert data into database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Here's my connection codes and query:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost' , 'root' , '#PASSWORD_HERE#' , 'NSEG');

    if($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Unable to connect!");
    }

    $Query = "INSERT INTO professors(id , Username , FirstName , LastName , Gender , Email) VALUES (NULL , '$username' , '$fname' , '$lname' , '$Gender' , '$Email')";
    $conn->query($Query);

    $conn->close();
```

But when I submit and I go to php my admin it doesn't show anything the "prfessors" table!
What Should I do?!

Comment: Have you gotten any errors?

Comment: Try running the query in phpmyadmin and check if the query works.

Comment: please add "mysqli_error($conn)"; before close() and update it in the question

Comment: @mohammad talaie, check the answer. let us know.

Comment: Guys it now inserts but there is still one problem When the data gets in the table in the id filed nothing displays and nothing has inserted for id? What is the problem?

Comment: Make id as primary key auto increament

Comment: How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1379Mohammad", "NSEG");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries

$query = "INSERT INTO professors(id , Username , FirstName , LastName , Gender , Email) VALUES (NULL , '$username' , '$fname' , '$lname' , '$Gender' , '$Email')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $query))
  {
  echo ("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Before trying the below PHP Snippet. Make sure the below points as well.

1. Make sure the `professors` table is exist.
2. Make sure `id` field is Primary Key and Auto increment.
3. Print the SQL Query and make sure all the values are non-empty.
4. check the mysqli_error, if any other error.

> SQL to Create Table with Primary Key and Auto Increment, Change other things as per your need.

```
CREATE TABLE `professors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: I think that my id field Is not auto increment..

Comment: What id already did is to set the id field to unsigned but I don't really know that would make it auto increment or not?

Comment: Export the table in phpmyadmin and share it. will tell you whether it has auto increment or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802410/how-to-export-a-single-table-from-phpmyadmin-to-a-comma-delimited-text-file

Comment: @mohammadtalaie, Added SQL statement to create table professor table or compare with your created one

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your id column is `PK` than do not pass `NULL` because it should be **auto increment**, try this:

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO professors(Username , FirstName , LastName , Gender , Email) VALUES ('$username' , '$fname' , '$lname' , '$Gender' , '$Email')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());

// select database 
mysql_select_db("1379Mohammad",$con);


//Insert values in professors table with column name 
$query="INSERT INTO professors(id , Username , FirstName , LastName , Gender , Email)
   VALUES (NULL , '$username' , '$fname' , '$lname' , '$Gender' , '$Email')";


if (mysql_query($query))
      {
      echo "Table empinfo created successfully";
      }
    else
      {
     echo  "Error creating database: " .mysql_error();
  }         

?>
```